# Datagridview not populating data from SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server-ce

I'm having an issue populating my data into a datagridview control. Here is my code.

```
string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Table;";
string source = "Data Source=E:\\Documents\\Database\\Database.sdf;" +
                "Password=password;Persist Security Info=False;";

SqlCeDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlCeDataAdapter(sqlQuery, source);
SqlCeCommandBuilder commBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);

DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

dataAdapter.Fill(table);

dbBindSource.DataSource = table;
dbGridView.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCellsExceptHeader);
dbGridView.ReadOnly = true;
dbGridView.DataSource = dbBindSource;
```

This is running on form load to no avail. Anyone?

Comment: You must run application in debug mode and ensure that each line of code do as expected.

Comment: if you put a breakpoint at `dbBindSource.DataSource = table;` and examine `table.Rows.Count()`, what do you see?

Comment: After I chose to exame table.Rows.Count() for some unknown reason, the data then populated the datagridview control.

Answer (score 0):

```
DataTable dataT;
BindingSource bindS;

using (SqlCeConnection yourConnection = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\YourDatabase.sdf")) {
    dataT = new DataTable();
    bindS = new BindingSource();    

    string query = "SELECT * FROM table01";
    SqlCeDataAdapter dA = new SqlCeDataAdapter(query, yourConnection);
    SqlCeCommandBuilder cBuilder = new SqlCeCommandBuilder(dA);
    dA.Fill(dataT);

    bindS.DataSource = dataT;
    DataGridView1.DataSource = bindS;
}
```

Resurrecting this with a working example because of the pages rank on google and because it was never answered.

Path is relative to your executing directory.